# Simple byte shifter not decrypting data the right way

Tags: visual-c++, encryption, byte, shift

i did not think i will someday ask a question here, but seeing that there are very good and talented programers here, i may have a chance to fix my problem...
I am using a simple BYTE shifter made by a friend, to encrypt packets like C1,C2,C3,C4( for a game ).
The crypting part from CLIENT SIDE is working OK, i have detoured send(), then calling crypt procedure.
The decrypting part from SERVER side is NOT OK at all, i tested the receive, it receives the same encrypted packet sent from CLIENT, but right after calling decrypt procedure it just does do it right.
On server side i used decrypting in IOCP::RecvDataParse.
Here is the procedure:

```
inline void process_data(const PROCESS_TYPE type, const BYTE (* keys)[KEYS_NUMBER], BYTE * pData, const unsigned int uLen)
{
    assert(pData != NULL);
    assert(type >= 0);
    assert(type <= 1);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uLen; ++i)
    {
        pData[i] = keys[type][pData[i]];
    }
}
```

and i call it like

process_data(DECRYPT, client_keys, lpIOContext->Buffer, lpIOContext->nSentBytes);

Ok so here are the results:

The original packet:         C1 06 A9 20 9C 2F

Encrypted packet wich is OK: 81 6f 4e 07 b8 89

The decrypted result packet: d5 b3 ee f6 c3 8d

So can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong? it`s been hours of testing and i got to nothing...

LE: i think it`s better if i post where i am calling the function... maybe i am wrong?

```
bool IOCP::RecvDataParse(_PER_IO_CONTEXT * lpIOContext, int uIndex)
{
    bool bReturn                = true;
    // ----
    UCHAR* recvbuf              = lpIOContext->Buffer;
    int lOfs                    = 0;
    int size                    = 0;
    BYTE headcode               = 0x00;
    BYTE xcode                  = 0x00;
    // ----

    if(lpIOContext->nSentBytes < 3) 
    {
        bReturn = false;
    }
    // ----
for (int i = 0; i < lpIOContext->nSentBytes; ++i)
    {

        OnError("ENCRYPTED : %02X", (BYTE) recvbuf[i]);

    }

while(true && bReturn)
    {
process_data(DECRYPT, client_keys, recvbuf, lpIOContext->nSentBytes);

//
for (int i = 0; i < lpIOContext->nSentBytes; ++i)
    {

        OnError("DECRYPTED : %02X", (BYTE) recvbuf[i]);
    }
    //OnError("[%s][DECRYPT] :: (Packets) %02X", m_Name, (BYTE) recvbuf);

        if((recvbuf[lOfs+0] == 0xC1) || (recvbuf[lOfs+0] == 0xC3))
        {
            size        = recvbuf[lOfs+1];
            headcode    = recvbuf[lOfs+2];
            xcode       = recvbuf[lOfs+0];

        }
        else if((recvbuf[lOfs+0] == 0xC2) || (recvbuf[lOfs+0] == 0xC4))
        {
            size        = recvbuf[lOfs+1] * 256;
            size        |=recvbuf[lOfs+2];
            headcode    = recvbuf[lOfs+3];
            xcode       = recvbuf[lOfs+0];

        }
        else
        {
            OnError("[%s][RecvDataParse] :: (ParseHeaderPacket) faill size %d headcode %x xcode %x", m_Name, size, headcode, xcode);
            // ----
            bReturn = false;
            // ----
            break;
        }
        if(size <= 0)
        {
            OnError("[%s][RecvDataParse] :: (RecvDataParse)  size %d", m_Name, size);
            // ----
            bReturn = false;
            // ----
            //CloseClient(lpIOContext->Buffer);
            break;
        }
        // ----
        if(size <= lpIOContext->nSentBytes)
        {
            OnRecv(uIndex, headcode, &recvbuf[lOfs], size);
            // ----
            lOfs                    += size;
            lpIOContext->nSentBytes -= size;
            // ----
            if(lpIOContext->nSentBytes <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if(lOfs > 0)
        {
            if(lpIOContext->nSentBytes < 1)
            {
                OnError("[%s][RecvDataParse] :: (RecvDataParse) recvbuflen 1 %s %d", m_Name, __FILE__, __LINE__);
                // ----
                break;
            }
            // ----
            if(lpIOContext->nSentBytes < MAX_IO_BUFFER_SIZE) 
            {
                memcpy(recvbuf, &recvbuf[lOfs], lpIOContext->nSentBytes);
                // ----
                OnError("[%s][RecvDataParse] :: (RecvDataParse) Message copy %d", m_Name, lpIOContext->nSentBytes);
            }
            // ----
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // ----

    return bReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all everything you wrote makes no sense.

An example for Byte Encryption (mostly used XOR encryption) is this:

```
#define MAX_PACKET_LENGTH 2048

char encrypt(char *String,char *Key) {  

    char output[MAX_LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(String); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;

    return output;
}

string decrypt(char *String,char *Key) {
    char output[MAX_LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(String); i++)
        output[i] = String[i] ^ key;

    return output;
}
```

Note that Encryption/Decryption key must be the same.

Comment: What do you mean it makes no sense? I just wanted to test in that function, because i tried detouring send() and recv(), and its the same problem.

client:
process_data(ENCRYPT, client_keys, buf, len);
server:
process_data(DECRYPT, client_keys, recvbuf, lpIOContext->nSentBytes);
Why do packet differ when decrypting? thats my problem... please help me! i pay if i have to!